# How can I assign the value 'null' 'this' in java?

Tags: java

How is it possible to assign the value null to this in Java? It's no problem to assign any certain value when using aliasing,

```
example = this;
example = something;
```

but it doesen't work when assigning null to example. Is there any possibility to circumvent this and assign null to the object whose method is called?

Comment: There is no such possibility. Why do you need this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is `example`? Could you provide the relevant code to replicate your problem?

Comment: Make a question more clear... What variable do you want assign null?

Comment: Any non-primitive variable can hold the value null. as in `Integer myInt=null;`

Comment: Assuming that `example` is a normal object reference, you can certainly assign `null` to it.  But that has nothing to do with the value of `this`, which you cannot modify.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is not a bad question.

Comment: This makes no sense. Your question smells strongly of an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), meaning you're likely barking up the wrong tree to solve whatever overriding problem that you have (and have yet to tell us). @lexicore: perhaps because the request makes no sense, but mostly because the OP has not noted any rationale whatsoever. I know that I will remove my down-vote if the OP tells more so that we can understand more about the background and the reasoning behind this request. He appears to be confusing object w/ variable.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well, he *is* confused, that is the whole point of the question. I think this is an interesting question, regardless of whether it comes out of the confusion or not.

Comment: @lexicore: it's perhaps interesting, but my down-vote was not for that reason. It was given because the question was unclear, and that is because he has not put in much effort in asking a clear question. Just a little more information would clear a lot of confusion. BTW, I did think that your answer was good.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possibility to circumvent this and assign null to the object whose method is called?

No, as you can't assign `null` to the *object*, only to the variable.

Comment: I don't understand your post. If you mean you cannot do `this = null;` then you're right, otherwise you're wrong because you can do `example = null`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I mean what I wrote. `example` is not and *object*, it is a variable.

Comment: it will fail if it's a primitive (int, float, etc)

Comment: Amen, the OP is confusing object with variable.

Comment: @spudone *you can ... assign `null` only to the variable* does not say *to variable of any type*. My point stands.

Comment: A more familiar way of differentiating might be *object* vs *object reference*.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Because if you create an object in java, it gets a certain place in memory. And all variables that refer to that object actually refer to that place. So if you say `this = null`, the compiler thinks, you want to set a variable - but `this` is not a variable, it's an object, or a place in memory.

Comment: This is only half correct. `this` is an object reference, not an object. The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3) says: "When used as a primary expression, the keyword `this` denotes a value that is a **reference to the object** for which the instance method was invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed." (my emphasis).

Comment: And that's where the problem lies. It doesn't say that `this` is a variable, it's just a reference. You can change a variable that holds a reference, not the reference itself. But this is not explicitly stated, it's implicit from the text.